# Ruby on Rails TypeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, marshalling, rvm, typeerror

I have been working on a ruby on rails application and ran into the following error when doing just about anything, including installing a gem, updating the bundle, installing the bundle.

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
    format version 4.8 required; 31.139 given`

I have uninstalled RVM and completely removed all files from it, then tried to install a gem, but still get the same error.

Comment: Some more info would be useful - what OS are you using? If RVM, run `rvm info` and paste the result; else run `ruby -v` , `gem env` and `which ruby; which gem; which rake` and paste the result.

Comment: check all your ~/.whatever files, also maybe clear some of your gem dirs? uninstall other versions of ruby?

Comment: `ruby -v`
`ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]`

Comment: `gem env`
`RubyGems Environment:  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: `- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-10`

Comment: `- GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /Users/devanb/.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8`

Comment: `- GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/`

Comment: Also when I opened up terminal I got the following:
`-bash: ./Users/devanb/.bashrc: No such file or directory`

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Mac OS X Snow Leopard also

Comment: Is it possible to reinstall or repair the native rails installation on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 6):

I had this exact problem, and it took me forever to figure it out. To fix it, I ran the following command:

```
bundle install --full-index
```

My guess is that I ended up with a corrupted rubygems index after my computer locked up, and this command forces a fresh download of the index.

Hopefully this helps someone who runs into this.

Answer (score 2):

Change the source in your gemfile to:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/pull/183