# Upgrading Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.2 getting 401 unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-4-2-1

When I updating to  from rails 3.2 to rails 4.2 the gems are all compatible for rails 4 was cross checked with [this](http://www.ready4rails4.net/gemfile_check/new) 
when I run server it will throwing error as below.

```
    Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

TypeError (incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
    format version 4.8 required; 123.34 given):
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/marshal.rb:6:in `load'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/marshal.rb:6:in `load_with_autoloading'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:424:in `deserialize'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:516:in `[]'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:114:in `get_cookie'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:90:in `block in unpacked_cookie_data'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:51:in `stale_session_check!'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:89:in `unpacked_cookie_data'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:83:in `block in extract_session_id'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:51:in `stale_session_check!'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:82:in `extract_session_id'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:49:in `block in []'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:48:in `fetch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:48:in `[]'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:70:in `id'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:282:in `current_session_id'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:288:in `session_exists?'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:152:in `exists?'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:172:in `load_for_read!'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:89:in `[]'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/session_serializer.rb:30:in `fetch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:212:in `user'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:318:in `_perform_authentication'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:104:in `authenticate'
  devise (3.5.2) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:120:in `current_user'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:290:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:290:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:290:in `each'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:290:in `all?'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:290:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `block in around'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
  client_side_validations (3.2.7) lib/client_side_validations/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.8) lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.8) lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:4:in `require'
  bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Is something missing for cookies or session settings or any changes required for devise?

I am facing different issue as well 
 [Rails 4 upgrade JSON::ParseError for old sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031985/rails-4-upgrade-jsonparseerror-for-old-sessions)

[Ruby on Rails TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201899/ruby-on-rails-typeerror)

But no luck I had changed secret token.

Comment: Would be easier if you show us some code

Answer (score 5):

It seem to be a checksum verification error. And in the callstack it comes just after CookieStore middleware. I'd try the following:

1. Empty cookies and cache in my web browser
2. If using server side cookie store: empty its storage (ex: empty the `sessions` database table when using `activerecord-session_store`)
3. Clean the content of my_app/tmp directory with `rake tmp:clear`

Comment: ..beacuse the way sessions are stored is not compatible between rails versions. You'll need to either monkeypatch to get the old sessions working, or retire all sessions (log everyone out). Since cookies are stored in browsers and you don't have access to all your users' machines, you'll probably have to change the name of the session key.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue when i upgraded from Rails 3.2.16 to Rails 4.2.0 and it was assets problem try do the following:

```
bundle exec rake assets:clean
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```